# old Javascript not refreshing in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, firefox, firefox4

I'm using Firefox 4 and Eclipse. I've made some edits to the js then I do Ctrl+F5 in the browser to use the new js, but I still keep getting the old js. Anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: Actually a refresh like this should **bust** any cache, even http cache headers.

Comment: @jAndy, I know, this is why I'm really ticked

Comment: @sameold: is the domain online and public available ?

Comment: @jAndy, no it's on my localhost

Comment: @sameold Just to make sure it's not cache, try opening it in private browsing.

Comment: @Truk, Hmm, it works fine in private browsing and I can see any changes I make immediately, so what's the issue?

Comment: @sameold It's caching it for some stupid reason. I set up a private browsing profile and link on my computer for when I'm developing, just to eliminate that problem.

Comment: No, i think you are thinking of ctrl+shift+r :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe caching? Try appending a ?12345 to the end of the src of the `<script>` like

`<script src="myscript.js?1234">`

Comment: This does the trick. I'll use it for now until I figure out what the problem is. It may be something with FF4, but it worked before.

Comment: It is something with FF4 :) if you turn off caching itll stop too. Most people append random numbers to the end of the URLs of scripts so it doesnt cache... view source on WP sites for example

Answer (score 0):

I get this all the time, caching never seems to work right.

Delete your history and refresh, and it should load the changes.